# How do I highlight all text and wrap in data exported from Access to Excel using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using VBA in Access to export a file into Excel and format the text in Excel.  I am trying to highlight all data in Excel (once it has been exported) and then wrap that data using VBA code in Access.

How would I get this task completed?

Trying to use the code below is not working.  The data starts in cell A1 and should end with the end xlright ans down (meaning, I do not have a set column or row where the data ends).

```
objApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
objApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Select
objApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
objApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Selection.End(xlDown).Select
objApp.Selection.WrapText = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the following would work clearly for you:

```
objApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).usedrange.wraptext=true
```